# why is hash output fixed in length?

Tags: algorithm, hash, message-digest

Hash functions always produce a fixed length output regardless of the input (i.e. MD5 >> 128 bits, SHA-256 >> 256 bits), but why?

I know that it is how the designer designed them to be, but why they designed the output to have the same length? 
So that it can be stored in a consistent fashion? easier to be compared? less complicated?

Comment: a hash is a condensed (lossy) version of the original data. There would be little point hashing data smaller than the hash size. It it were smaller, then you could probably recover it....

Comment: even hashing of the bigger data produces the same size, no? My question is why did the designer design it to be as such though...

Comment: A varying size would presumably give some clues to original composition(?)

Comment: That sound possible too, @MitchWheat :D
It is also because of the memory issue as described by j_random_hacker I think :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because that is what the definition of a hash is. Refer to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function)

> A **hash function** is any function that can be used to map digital data
>   of arbitrary size to digital data of **fixed size**.

If your question relates to why it is **useful** for a hash to be a fixed size there are multiple reasons (non-exhaustive list):

- Hashes typically encode a larger (often arbitrary size) input into a smaller size, generally in a lossy way, i.e. unlike compression functions, you cannot reconstruct the input from the hash value by "reversing" the process.
- Having a fixed size output is convenient, especially for hashes designed to be used as a lookup key.
- You can predictably (pre)allocate storage for hash values and index them in a contiguous memory segment such as an array.
- For hashes of "native word sizes", e.g. 16, 32 and 64 bit integer values, you can do very fast equality and ordering comparisons.
- Any algorithm working with hash values can use a single set of fixed size operations for generating and handling them.
- You can predictably combine hashes produced with different hash functions in e.g. a [bloom filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter).
- You don't need to waste any space to encode how big the hash value is.

There do exist special hash functions, that are capable of producing an output hash of a specified fixed length, such as so-called [sponge functions](http://sponge.noekeon.org/).

Answer (score 1):

As you can see it is the [standard](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips180-4/fips-180-4.pdf).

Also what you want is specified in standard :

> Some application may require a hash function with a message digest
>   length different than those provided by the hash functions in this
>   Standard. In such cases, a truncated message digest may be used,
>   whereby a hash function with a larger message digest length is applied
>   to the data to be hashed, and the resulting message digest is
>   truncated by selecting an appropriate number of the leftmost bits.

Answer (score 1):

Often it's because you want to use the hash value, or some part of it, to quickly store and look up values in a fixed-size array.  (This is how a non-resizable hashtable works, for example.)

And why use a fixed-size array instead of some other, growable data structure (like a linked list or binary tree)?  Because accessing them tends to be both theoretically and practically fast: provided that the hash function is good and the fraction of occupied table entries isn't too high, you get O(1) lookups (vs. O(log n) lookups for tree-based data structures or O(n) for lists) on average.  And these accesses are fast in practice: after calculating the hash, which usually takes linear time in the size of the key with a low hidden constant, there's often just a bit shift, a bit mask and one or two indirect memory accesses into a contiguous block of memory that (a) makes good use of cache and (b) pipelines well on modern CPUs because few pointer indirections are needed.